# How can I make the sidebar-width the default?

Tags: nautilus, window, dconf, gsettings

I want resize the sidebar-width to the default.

[image]

Comment: You could install dconf-tool and assign it default dimensions. Select org → gnome → nautilus → window-state → sidebar-width

Comment: @YashKhosla you might want to post that as an answer (using `dconf-editor`). Please add the command `gsettings reset org.gnome.nautilus.window-state sidebar-width`, which would reset the key without installing anything.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If it's not very problematic, try to keep the image size smaller. The settings will be in the screenshot tool. That helps people with limited bandwidth :)

Comment: Hi elon, posted. Please mrntion if all is clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! i have resolved this problem ! this problem cause by the name of items on sidebar is too long so that we can't drag the central line to resize !

Answer (score 2):

The sidebar-width is stored in the `dconf` database, which is best edited with `gsettings` (`gsettings` is the cli frontend to `dconf`).

You can do that either by GUI or command line:

#### 1. GUI

- Install `dconf-editor`:

  ```
  sudo apt-install dconf-editor
  ```
- Then navigate to "org" > "gnome" > "nautilus" > "window-state", and click on "sidebar-width". subsequently, either set a new value or click on <kbd>Set to Default</kbd> at the right/bottom of the window.

  [image]

#### 2. From command line

Either:

- run the command:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state sidebar-width 200
  ```

  to set a specific value, or:

  ```
  gsettings reset org.gnome.nautilus.window-state sidebar-width
  ```

  to reset to default (188 px)